# Random background image on refresh

Tags: jquery, image, web

I'm attempting to to randomly load an image each time a user visits the site. I've followed a tutorial and a couple of previous threads on the issue and can't seem to get it working. The images are in the /images/ folder and the filenames are correctly entered into the array:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  var images = ['OUT01ari.jpg' 'OUT02adobe.jpg' 'OUT03alife.jpg' 'OUT04chinup.jpg' 'OUT05datenightwinecologne.jpg' 'OUT06officechair.jpg' 'OUT07printer.jpg' 'OUT08whitewall.jpg' 'OUT09umbrella.jpg' 'OUT10converse.jpg' 'OUT11wardrobebar.jpg'];

  $('#background').css({'background-image': 'url(images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'});

</script>
```

I've then entered the div in the body of the page, but to no avail:

```
<body>

<div ="#background"></div>
<div class="container">

</div>
</body>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You must have comma separators between the array values when you define your array.

You should also have two separate script elements, one for including jquery and the other for your code.

The content of a script tag with a src-attribute should be ignored by most browsers.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var images = ['OUT01ari.jpg', 'OUT02adobe.jpg', 'OUT03alife.jpg', 'OUT04chinup.jpg', 'OUT05datenightwinecologne.jpg', 'OUT06officechair.jpg', 'OUT07printer.jpg', 'OUT08whitewall.jpg', 'OUT09umbrella.jpg', 'OUT10converse.jpg', 'OUT11wardrobebar.jpg'];
 $('#background').css({'background-image': 'url(images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'});
</script>
```

[W3C 4.3 Scripting HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html) says:

> If there is a src attribute, the element must be either empty or
>   contain only script documentation that also matches script content
>   restrictions.

And the same is true for earlier versions I believe.

**Edit:**

If you are working on the local file system , make sure to change the URL to jQuery to **http://** instead of just **//**.

Also, make sure your script is executed when the #background element exists by calling in on [document ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

This example should work even locally:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style type="text/css">
   #background { 
    position:fixed; left: 0px; 
    top: 0px; background-size:100%;  
     width:100%; height:100%; 
     -webkit-user-select: none; -khtml-user-select: none; 
     -moz-user-select: none; -o-user-select: none; user-select: none; 
      z-index:9990; 
    }
  </style>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
    var images = ['OUT01ari.jpg', 'OUT02adobe.jpg', 'OUT03alife.jpg', 'OUT04chinup.jpg', 'OUT05datenightwinecologne.jpg', 'OUT06officechair.jpg', 'OUT07printer.jpg', 'OUT08whitewall.jpg', 'OUT09umbrella.jpg', 'OUT10converse.jpg', 'OUT11wardrobebar.jpg'];
    $('#background').css({'background-image': 'url(images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'});
   });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="background"></div>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, I've amended these errors along with the errors pointed out by isherwood and and jacouh but the images still aren't loading.

Comment: I created a fiddle that works: http://jsfiddle.net/ffXUC/ - though it's hard to say why yours is not. Have you checked the browser console / web developer tools (F12 in Chrome) for any errors?

Comment: Thank you - and no I hadn't. The error I get is: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined index.html:11
(anonymous function). Line 11 being:   $ ('#background').css({'background-image': 'url(images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'});

Comment: I edited my answer - I guess the $ error probably occurs because you're working locally on your computer? Then the // in the src url will attempt to get jQuery from the file system. You should also execute your script when the document is ready, or the #background element will not yet exist. I edited my answer above and added an example that works for me locally.

Comment: Thank you. I wrote your jQuery code letter for letter and was missing the initial function() call. The only issue is that every so often no image will load, which I assume is related to the math used to determine the randomised image loading?

Comment: How would I add a fade transition to the images? :-/ Css or JS ? Any help please :)

Answer (score 3):

```
<div ="#background"></div>
```

should be

```
<div id="background"></div>
```

(Or was that just a typo?)

Comment: `<div id="#background"></div>` should be `<div id="background"></div>`

Comment: Thanks. Fixed. Tired eyes. :-D

Answer (score 0):

To show background-image, a div must have some size/area, have-you tried this ?

```
<body>

<div id="background" style="width: 50px; height: 60px;"></div>
<div class="container">

</div>
</body>
```

?

Comment: I'd already given the background div width and height properties of 100% so the image would fill the screen: #background {
 position:fixed;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 background-size:100%;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -o-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
 z-index:9990;
}