# Is there a way to add background when using css3 multiple backgrounds images?

Tags: css, background, background-image

I am using css3 multiple backgrounds images.
I wonder if it is possible to add top layer background with pseudo-classes like :hover or :active?

Comment: You could override the background image with Javascript, or if the background images are being applied to a div you could just swap it out with the `:hover` selector `.bg-div:hover { background:url('path/to/image.jpg'); }`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to have pseudo-classes work with your background. but it would get your users an uncomfortable User experience with `:hover` or `:active`.

You can apply **CSS** to multiple div like this:

```
.background1.background2{
    background-image: url(background1.png), url(background2.png);
    background-position: center, center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
    backgroun-size: 100%, 50%
}
```

or you can apply **CSS** to multiple div like this (depend how you want your Image to be presented to browser:

```
.background1{
    background-image: url(background1.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.background2{
    background-image: url(background2.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 50%;
}
```

if you want to change background randomly by itself then i would recommend using CSS3 Animation or jQuery change on refresh.

[CSS3 Animation](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)
[jQuery Change on Refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19369552/2556515)

Comment: I just want to add a background image to css3 multiple background images (I don't need to change the entire background).

Comment: Please take a look at the answer again. :)