# Randomize images to display on homepage background

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, background-image

How I can have background images changing each time someone visits a homepage? The current background image is controlled in the CSS, not HTML so any help would be greatly appreciated.

See CSS for the single background image:

```
 header .container-fluid
 {
 background-image: url("../../images/The Connection at St-Martin-in-the- 
 Fields/Carousel image - med res The Connection -1067838.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 height: 100vh;
 padding-top: 36px;
 }
```

Comment: You can make an array with the image paths in jquery and pick a random image every time?

Comment: what google say ? i think he know such stuff

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827691/random-body-background-image/8827745 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369426/random-background-image-on-refresh for starters...

Comment: Robin, can you help me with this?

Comment: My issue is the background image that is defined by CSS

Comment: The solutions in the links I posted will override / change the background image defined in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a little JavaScript to your page to change the image on page load:

```
// make a list of images to select from
var images = ['cat.jpg', 'dog.jpg'];

// find the element whose background image you want to change
var elem = document.querySelector('header .container-fluid');

// get the index position of the image in `images` to be displayed
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);

// set the background image property
elem.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[index] + ')';
```

The background image set by JavaScript will have priority over the CSS style, so the image set by JavaScript will be displayed.

Comment: floor function is more appropriate than parseInt

Comment: @duhaime thanks for this, I tried adding it but nothing seems to change when I place my own images in the relevant areas of the code

Comment: @JustJoel make sure you post the code above between `<script>` and `</script>`, and make sure you place that full script block as the last block before `</body>` on your page. So the end of your HTML document should look like `</script></body></html>`. This will ensure the JS code is the last thing to operate on your page, and will make sure that the HTML selected by the JS code above is present when the JS code tries to find the relevant element.

Comment: Thanks for that, one last thing, how would i change the image directory on the js code?

Comment: @JustJoel the easiest way to proceed is to make your images available to your server. So if you're hosting on `http://localhost:5000` and that server is running in `C:\App`, add your images to `C:\App\images`. Then you should be able to define your image list like `var images = ["images/cat.jpg", "images/dog.jpg"];` I hope that helps!