# Random background for elementor

Tags: javascript, wordpress, random, background-image, elementor

I use Elementor pro in my site. I have big Background image in top of my homepage that I have many elements in that section. I want to have one random image from a group of images (can be in gallery or in folder). but i didn't fine any solution.

I tried any addon for elementor. elementor pro background slidet, the plus row background, and etc. but they only make a slides with default order and don't have random order. I also tried some slider plugin or elementor's slider addons (smart slider,...). but the elements that should be on the image (other than text and buttons) could not be added to them.

I tried some javascripts to do it (for example: https://element.how/elementor-slider-random/#comment-12854 and this: [Random background image on refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369426/random-background-image-on-refresh)). but it didn't work.

I like to know there is any solution to use custom php code to elementor dynamic simple background image that apply all background setting?

is there any solution?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected function render() {
    $settings = $this->get_settings_for_display();

    $images = array_values( $settings['carousel'] ?? [] );
    if ( ! $images ) {
        return;
    }
    $count = count( $images );
    $image = random_int( 0, ( $count - 1 ) );
    $image = $images[ $image ] ?? null;
    if ( ! $image ) {
        return;
    }

    $image_url = Group_Control_Image_Size::get_attachment_image_src( $image['id'], 'full', [ 'full_size' => 'full' ] );

    echo '<img class="' . $this->get_name() . '-image" src="' . esc_attr( $image_url ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( Control_Media::get_image_alt( $image ) ) . '" />';
}
```

Elementor  create a custom widget and follow the code. I hope your problem will be solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: so thank fo your attention. but i have some quetion: I must create custom widget? I didn't create custom widget before and I will search about that. but in that widget elementor effects for example background transition how will be applyed?